# is QuickTime available on OSX 10.9.5?

Tags: macos, mac, quicktime

I'm using OSX 10.9.5 on my MacBook Pro now and I can't find the QuickTime app/feature anywhere. Is QuickTime only available on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3? If it is on OSX 10.9.5, where is it located? It's not one of my the apps at the bottom of screen, so where can it be?

I want to make a preview video for my app and I need QuickTime and iMovie to do it. But also, where is iMovie located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Finder and type <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. That will get you to your applications (hence the "a"). QuickTime and iMovie should both be there.